# Why do i encounter an errror when I compile using make -j command in cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I am trying to compile a software environment in Cygwin using make -j command and this error always shows up.

!error Hello World>

/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'

make: ***[makefile:404: ] Error 1

Comment: please provide more details. What is in the make file ? It seems the error is coming from a shell execution and not from make itself. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Make sure your shell script has LF line endings instead of CR+LF line endings. Use the `d2u FILE` command to change the file's line endings. You may need to install the `dos2unix` package using the cygwin setup app.